# Could not load file or assembly ' Version=, PublicKeyToken=null or one of its dependencies.A strongly-named assembly is required

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have a third party assembly that I have given a strong name and deployed as part of my app and I'm getting the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly ' Version=, PublicKeyToken=null or one of its dependencies.A strongly-named assembly is required.

I signed it using the following command:

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ilasm" /dll /key="$(ProjectDir)mykey.snk" XXX.il /Output="$(SolutionDir)packages\XXX.2.71.1\lib\net40\XXX.dll"
```

I understand from the following question, that the error is occurring because I'm referencing a copy of the assembly that does not have a strong name. Yet when I look at the properties of my references, they all say Strong Name - True.
Could something else be the problem?

[Assembly has a strong name, but I"m getting the error that says a strong name is needed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148475/assembly-has-a-strong-name-but-im-getting-the-error-that-says-a-strong-name-is)

Comment: you say " that I have given a strong name" - do you mean you signed the assembly?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the post above with the sign command.